# How to match a question mark?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to search and replace a list of URLs in a file and I am having problems if the search URL has a question mark in it. The `$file` below is just a single tag here, but it is usually an entire file.

```
my $search = 'http://shorturl.com/detail.cfm?color=blue';
my $replace = 'http://shorturl.com/detaila.aspx?color=red';
my $file = '<a href="http://shorturl.com/detail.cfm?color=blue" class="news">HI</a>';
$file =~ s/$search/$replace/gis;
print $file;
```

If the `$search` variable has `?` in it the substitution does not work. It would work if I were to take off the `?color=blue` from the `$search` variable.

Does anyone know how to make the above substitution work? Backslashing, i.e. `\?` did not help. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) for the regex pattern.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $search = quotemeta 'http://shorturl.com/detail.cfm?color=blue';
my $replace = 'http://shorturl.com/detaila.aspx?color=red';
my $file = '<a href="http://shorturl.com/detail.cfm?color=blue" class="news">HI</a>';
$file =~ s/$search/$replace/gis;
print $file;

__END__

<a href="http://shorturl.com/detaila.aspx?color=red" class="news">HI</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

When a string is interpolated as a regex, it isn't matched literally, but interpreted as a regex. This is useful to build complex regexes, e.g.

```
my @animals = qw/ cat dog goldfish /;
my $animal_re = join "|", @animals;

say "The $thing is an animal" if $thing =~ /$animal_re/i;
```

In the string `$animal_re`, the `|` is treated as a regex metacharacter.

Other metacharacters are e.g. `.`, which matches any non-newline character, or `?`, which makes the previous atom optional.

If you want to match the contents of a variable literally, you can enclose it in `\Q...\E` quotes:

```
s/\Q$search/$replace/gi
```

(The `/s` option just changes the meaning of `.` from “match any non-newline character” to “match any character”, and is therefore irrelevant here.)

The `\Q...\E` is syntactic sugar for the `quotemeta` function, therefore this answer and [toolic](/users/197758/toolic)'s [answer](/a/17426556/1521179) are exactly equivalent.

Comment: @devnull The closing `\E` is optional when the pattern is terminated anyway.

Comment: Thanks. The quotemeta adds the meta tags just like that. The s is there because I am searching a file not just a single line. The example just uses a single line to be brief. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you want to escape more than just the `?`.  The `?` is the only one in your example that messes up what you're expecting, but the `.` matching can be insidious to find.

The regex `/foo.com/` will indeed match the string `foo.com`, but it will also match `foo com` and `fooXcom` and `foo!com`, because `.` matches any character.  Therefore, the `/foo.com/` should be written as `/foo\.com/`.